# argument of type "int*" is incompatible with parameter of type "int**" error in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, header

I was asked by my professor to create functions and use pointers to
pass an array of integers as parameter for each of those functions but when I inserted the test code that he created, I got the argument of type "int*" is incompatible with parameter of type "int**" errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "homework.h"
using namespace std;


int main() {
int a[10] = { 3, 5, 6, 8, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 20 };
int b[6] = { 18, 16, 19, 3 ,14, 6 };
int c[5] = { 5, 2, 4, 3, 1 };

Homework h;
// testing initialize_array
h.print_array(a, 10); // ERROR
h.initialize_array(a, 10); // ERROR
h.print_array(a, 10); // ERROR

h.print_array(b, 6); // ERROR
h.selection_sort(b, 6); // ERROR
h.print_array(b, 6); // ERROR

cout << "Factorial of 5 = " << h.factorial (5) <<endl; //print: 120
    c[0] = h.factorial(c[0]);
c[1] = h.factorial(c[2]);
h.print_array(c, 5); // ERROR
return 0;
})
```

Here is the source file for Homework:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "homework.h"
using namespace std;

void Homework::initialize_array(int *numArr[], int size)
{

for (int count = 0; count < size; count++) {
    // if divisible by 2, replace the value to 0.
    if (count % 2 == 0) {
        *numArr[count] = 0;
    }
    else {
        *numArr[count] = 1;
    }
}
}

void Homework::print_array(int *numArr[], int size)
{
// prints each values in the array.
for (int count = 0; count < size; count++) {
    if (count == 0) {
        cout << *numArr[count];
    }
    else {
        cout << ", " << *numArr[count];
    }
}
cout << endl;
}

void Homework::selection_sort(int *numArr[], int size)
{
int i, j, minIndex;

// determine the minimum value.
for (i = size - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    minIndex = 0;
    for (j=1; j<=i; j++) {
        if (*numArr[j] < *numArr[minIndex])
            minIndex = j;
    }

    // swap values.
    int temp = *numArr[minIndex];
    *numArr[minIndex] = *numArr[i];
    *numArr[i] = temp;
}
}

 int Homework::factorial(int num)
{
 if (num == 0 || num == 1)
    return 1;
else
    // if not 0 or 1, recall the function.
    return(num * factorial(num - 1));
}
```

Comment: You are handing an int array and it is looking for a pointer to an int array

Comment: In a function parameter, `int*[]` is just syntax sugar for `int**`. That makes sense to use in a function that needs to alter a caller's pointer to an array, but that does not make sense for any of the functions in this homework assignment. All of the `Homework` methods shown should be using `int[]` parameters instead, which is syntax sugar for `int*`.  An `int[]` array decays to an `int*` pointer to its 1st element, which is what all of these methods need. If you are using the `Homework` class exactly as your professor gave it to you, then he gave you bad (well, misleading) code to start with

Comment: My professor provided the main class but the last time I did what Remy said, I lost points for not using pointers to pass the array as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your professor wants to show pointers you can do this:

```
void Homework::print_array(int *numArr, int size)//exact same as int numArr[] as it decays to a pointer
{
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++) {
    if (count == 0) {
        cout << numArr[count];
    }
    else {
        cout << ", " << numArr[count];
    }
}
cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
   int a[10] = { 3, 5, 6, 8, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 20 };

    Homework h;

    h.print_array(a, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: was thinking maybe your prof wanted you to demonstrate an array of pointers like this:

```
void Homework::print_array(int *numArr[], int size)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++) {
    if (count == 0) {
        cout << *numArr[count];
    }
    else {
        cout << ", " << *numArr[count];
    }
}
cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
   int a[10] = { 3, 5, 6, 8, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 20 };
   int* arrayPtr[10];
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
       arrayPtr[i] = &a[i];
   }    
    Homework h;   
    h.print_array(arrayPtr, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what my professor is looking for. Can't believe I just had to delete the brackets to make it all work...

Comment: I have a hard time believing a professor wants this as IMO it is bad code because it is not as readable as 9694 but exactly the same..GL though:)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have an array of pointers. You should have an array of ints <s>`int *numArr[]`</s>:

```
void Homework::print_array(int numArr[], int size) //remove the extra * on front
{
// prints each values in the array.
for (int count = 0; count < size; count++) {
    if (count == 0) {
        cout << numArr[count];
    }
    else {
        cout << ", " << numArr[count];
    }
}
cout << endl;
}
```

Well if you have to use `int *numArr[]`, then **keep the original print_array** function, but if you try printing it, use `h.print_array(&a, 10);`.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but then what does my professor mean when he says, I need to use pointers to pass the array as a parameter?

Comment: @LotChannel What did you try that he didn't consider using pointers to pass the array as a parameter?

Comment: He docked points when I didn't use int *numArr[] and used int numArr[] instead.